# C# Tip calculator, method not calling, no error message

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TipCalculator
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string answer;
        float totalPrice;
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to calculate a tip?");
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the total price of your meal");
            totalPrice = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (totalPrice >= 20.00)
                TipCalculator.over20(totalPrice);
            else if (totalPrice < 20)
                TipCalculator.under20(totalPrice);
            else Console.WriteLine("Error. Please type in the value of the bill again");

        }
        else if (answer == "no")
            Console.WriteLine("Please run this again when you wish to calculate a tip.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Error. Please type in \"yes\" or \"no\"");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
public class TipCalculator
{
    public static string over20(float bill)

    {
      float tip, totalBill;
      tip = (bill * (float)1.2);
      totalBill = (tip + bill);
      return "Very good. The total tip to be paid is " + tip + " and this will cost " + totalBill + "in total.";

    }

    public static string under20(float bill)
    {
        float tip, totalBill;
        tip = (bill * (float)1.1);
        totalBill = (tip + bill);
        return "Very good. The total tip to be paid is " + tip + " and this will cost " + totalBill + "in total.";

    }
}
}
```

When I try to run this code no error is displayed however the message starting with "Very good" does not display in the over20 or under20 message. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The methods only return the strings, but you're not printing them anywhere.

Comment: thank you! but when I replaced return with console.readline I got different errors. How would I print those strings? EDIT: Never mind, I got it and thank you! I understand where I went wrong!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you are returning string from methods `over20` and `under20`, but you are not using them anywhere. Update the part of your code to print the output using `Console.WriteLine`:

```
if (totalPrice >= 20.00)
    Console.WriteLine(TipCalculator.over20(totalPrice));
else if (totalPrice < 20)
    Console.WriteLine(TipCalculator.under20(totalPrice));
else Console.WriteLine("Error. Please type in the value of the bill again");
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4BsyaV)